# Unable to get Main and Backup Routers to connect to each other

Tags: networking, router, routing, iptables

I have two networks and routers (both on Advanced Tomato by Shibby) laid out as such:

1. Backup Router network (192.168.1.1/24)

   1. WAN - Xfinity
   2. LAN - small number of clients. Importantly, main network router is a client on this network.
   3. Network interfaces

      1. br0 - local. Router has IP 192.168.1.1
      2. eth0 - Xfinity
      3. eth2 - Wireless network - this is the network on which the backup network is connected as a Wireless client
2. Main Router network (192.168.2.1/24)

   1. WAN - Fiber
   2. LAN - Connected to mesh networking access points. Almost all of the devices in the house are connected via these Mesh networking access points to the main network. Especially important are my local NAS, and services hosts e.g. Plex, Printers and Gaming desktop.
   3. Load balancing - This router is a "Wireless client" on the backup network router, and has Multi-WAN with load balancing enabled.
   4. Network interfaces

      1. br0 - local. Router has IP 192.168.2.1
      2. eth0 - Fiber
      3. eth2 - client on Backup network with IP 192.168.1.81

**How it's working**: As long as the client is on the main network, the system works well. They are able to access the NAS, printer etc. They are also able to access and ping any client on the backup network.

**Problem**:

The problem happens when the client is on the backup network. The clients on the backup network aren't able to reach the NAS, printer etc on the main network.

What I have tried: I have tried to allow the backup router to enable it's clients to reach the main router network. I found a few articles mentioning doing this and performed the following steps:

1. I have tried adding the following iptables forwarding to Backup network

```
    iptables -I INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -I FORWARD -i eth2 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -d 10.9.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

2. Enabling ip packet forwarding on BOTH backup and main networks
   By running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
3. Add ip route
   `ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.81`

**Issues**

Unfortunately, this is not working. When I try to ping 192.168.2.1 from my backup network router, I am getting the error - `Unable to ping From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host (New nexthop 192.168.1.81)`.

My guess is I am messing up on the iptables part. I do not fully understand what I am doing there. If someone can please help, I would deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried adding the following iptables forwarding to Backup network

The FORWARD rules don't seem to match your network description:

- Packets arriving into the backup router's eth2 (i.e. coming from the main router) would have 192.168.2.0/24 as their *source,* not destination; and likewise, packets sent to 192.168.2.0/24 would be exiting eth2, not entering it (i.e. if that's the `-d`, then it should be `-o eth2`).

  If you visualize the packets, in both directions, you should have something like this:

  | Source address | Dst address | Input interface | Output interface |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 192.168.1.0/24 | 192.168.2.0/24 | →br0 | eth2→ |
  | 192.168.2.0/24 | 192.168.1.0/24 | →eth2 | br0→ |

  You can add rules with just `-s` and `-d`, or with interfaces, etc. I would suggest looking at the packet counters in the iptables rules list to check whether the rules are being *matched* by any packets.
- The 10.9.8.0/24 network doesn't seem to be involved anywhere.
- The INPUT rule is not relevant, as none of your packets are "input" to the router – that would only be the case if you were pinging the router's *own* address.

  For example, if you were pinging the main router, that would be "forward" for the backup router and "input" for the main router. But if you're pinging one client from another, that's classified as "forward" for all routers involved (and "input" only for the client itself).

While this is necessary, it should generally be a step after you've added routes, not before. Always keep in mind that IPtables only controls whether packets are *allowed* to be forwarded in a particular direction, but doesn't control *where* they should be forwarded – the routing table decides that first, and then you tailor iptables FORWARD rules to that.

> Enabling ip packet forwarding on BOTH backup and main networks By running echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

They're routers – the Tomato firmware will already have packet forwarding enabled from the factory, as that's basically the purpose of a router, and it's how you're getting Internet access right now.

> When I try to ping 192.168.2.1 from my backup network router, I am getting the error - Unable to ping From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host (New nexthop 192.168.1.81).

That is not an error. That's an optional message where the backup router indicates that a more direct path is available (bypassing the router); you would normally see it *in addition* to the usual responses.

The actual error is the absence of replies, which is most likely caused either by the "backup" router's *or* the "main" router's firewall rules blocking packets in that direction.

Use tcpdump (`tcpdump -n -i ... "icmp"`) to check where packets arrive and exit:

- Do they reach the *main* router's eth2 interface?

  - If they don't, then the backup router isn't forwarding them (either iptables or routing table might be wrong).
  - If they do: Do they reach the main router's br0 interface, too?

    - If they don't, then the main router isn't forwarding them (it already has local routes for the destination, which leaves its iptables rules don't allow it).
    - If they do reach br0: Does the client try to respond?

      - If it doesn't, then the client's own firewall might be blocking it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I added the iptables rules: 
````iptables --insert FORWARD --src 192.168.2.0/24 --dst 192.168.1.0/24 --jump ACCEPT````
````iptables --insert FORWARD --src 192.168.1.0/24 --dst 192.168.2.0/24 --jump ACCEPT```` 

Pinging from the backup router to the main router is still failing with the following tcpdump:
````IP 192.168.1.69 > 192.168.2.1: ICMP echo request, id 6, seq 1, length 64````
````IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.69: ICMP redirect 192.168.2.1 to host 192.168.1.81, length 92````.

I am guessing that means there is still a backup router iptables issue?